# Why is dmidecode returning "Bochs" for a VM running under QEMU?

Tags: linux, qemu, linux-kvm, bochs

In all information I've found Bochs and QEMU are two separate solutions for emulate/virtualize computers. So I got really confused when I got the results below in my Linux-VM running in QEMU.

```
root@www1:~# lscpu | grep ^Model
Model:                 2
Model name:            QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12
root@www1:~# dmidecode | egrep -i 'vendor'
        Vendor: Bochs
root@www1:~# dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product'
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Product Name: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
        Manufacturer: Bochs
root@www1:~# dmidecode -s system-product-name
Bochs
root@www1:~# dmidecode | grep Product
        Product Name: Bochs
root@www1:~# dmidecode -s system-manufacturer
Bochs
```

Does anyone have any idea why Bochs is mentioned in my QEMU-VM?

I'm only asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [QEMU version 4.2.0 User Documentation](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html):

> QEMU uses the PC BIOS from the Seabios project and the Plex86/Bochs LGPL VGA BIOS.